# Fetch image only once and display it multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Suppose I have a single page containing image and button. When I open the page, the image is rendered and button is displayed. When I click the button, the browser redirects to other page and displays the image in full view. This is pretty simple with doing

```
 <img src="url"/>
```

for both pages. But I want to make a call only once to fetch the image. Even if I open the first page, wait for one day, then come back and click the button, the new page should not cause additional call to fetch the image. Can you help me how can I do that?

Comment: The browser should handle all the caching for you automatically, you could do it manually, but it's really not worth it.

Comment: That sounds like a simple caching thing. You may have the opportunity to set up your server to set a huge cache time to the image files on your server. Then the browser will get the image from the cache when the page requests it. Is it that what you mean?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control for cache. I need another way. Something like, to fetch the image in browser memory, and use it afterwards anywhere I need it.

Comment: You have just described browser caching, unless the server is specifically preventing it, the browser should automatically do exactly what you just said: Store the image locally and reuse it when it needs to. (Some things like memory availability might mean it has to be re-fetched, but those would also apply to any custom solution you write)